# How can I track when a user uses an input field to stop the backend from updating an input field when user is typing?

Tags: reactjs, input, react-hooks, next.js

Often our database updates the forms/files/input fields that our users are working on live (e.g. a background job updates the fields with new info).

The form updates right in front of their eyes which they enjoy.

However if they're typing into a specific input field as the update runs, whatever they were typing in that moment gets overwritten, which is annoying.

We would rather whatever the user was writing would take priority and overwrite what the db is pushing upwards into that input field.

A solution I'm hoping for is temporarily storing whatever the user is typing in case an update happens so that we can put that local state back into the input field after they finish typing. This should overwrite whatever the db sent.

How would you do this?

Is it possible to somehow track which input field the user is touching and just protect that specific input field from the db field and not the other fields not currently being modified by the user?

E.g something like this: (I'm mixing in pseudo code here):

```
<Input
  disabled={!canEdit}
  value={

     if(userIsTypingHere){
      currentLocalInput
     } 
     else{dbData?.docTitle


    }
  placeholder="Title (mandatory)"
  fontSize={'xl'}
  isInvalid={!dbData?.title}
  onChange={(e) =>
    setOurDoc({
      ...dbData,
      docTitle: e.target.value,
    })
  }
/>

<Input
  disabled={!canEdit}
  value={

     if(userIsTypingHere){
      currentLocalInput
     } 
     else{dbData?.docDecription


    }
  placeholder="Title (mandatory)"
  fontSize={'xl'}
  isInvalid={!dbData?.description}
  onChange={(e) =>
    setOurDoc({
      ...dbData,
      docTitle: e.target.value,
    })
  }
/>
```

The alternative is storing the state from the backend, a temporary holding state and a final state that is presented to the user. But this could get messy quickly and I would rather use the solution above.

Thoughts?
**
Extra Info:**
We're using:
NextJs
Chakra UI

Side note:
After this is done if the user input overwrites the db update this new input is saved to the db automatically and so will stay persistent.

Comment: What are the criteria for "writing"? Input focus? Character entry within some time span? Rather than restoring a value, delay updates until a more appropriate time, or give the user the option to accept the update.

Comment: My suggestion would be that, if an input has focus, a control appears that lets the user decide whether to accept the update. Maybe a tooltip shows the new value.

Comment: what happens when user stops typing and you store users value in input, and **afterwards** DB sends a new value?

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava After this is done if the user input overwrites the db update this new input is saved to the db automatically and so will stay persistent.

Comment: @isherwood Thanks for the quick reply! Having the pointer still inside the input field would ideally constitute writing.

Comment: "The form updates right in front of their eyes which they enjoy." Note that the backend doesn't do this. The frontend ALWAYS has control and initiates any communication with the backend. There is something in your frontend code that causes this update. You will need to find where that is in order to solve the problem.

Comment: Please update your question with that information. It doesn't belong down here.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice this is true. We load it in from firebase and then update our local state for the doc.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like 'userIsTypingHere' should act like dirty flag - set it on true when the user starts typing - on change, and back on false when the input is blurred, or maybe after a few seconds, or on save - depending on your business case. You'd probably need a state for your controlled input.

You could update the input in a useEffect if the userIsTypingHere is false.

I see it something like this:

```
const [userIsTypingHere, setUserIsTypingHere] = useState(false); 
const [currentLocalInput, setCurrentLocalInput] = useState(false);  

useEffect(() => {
  if(!userIsTypingHere) setCurrentLocalInput(dbValue);
}, [dbValue]);

return (
  <Input 
     value={userIsTypingHere ? currentLocalInput : dbValue}
     onChange={(e) => {setUserIsTypingHere(true); setCurrentLocalInput(e.target.value);}}
     onBlur={(e) => {setUserIsTypingHere(false); doStuff(); }} // save to backend or manage conflict
   />
```

Comment: Thanks a million, this is a great idea, but unfortunately I have multiple input fields and so this would affect all of them. I will update my question to reflect this!

Comment: @GarryTiscovschi You could wrap the code above in a component and use it instead of the input. 
Or, if you're concerned with adding too many states, you can move this to the level of the form. Instead of the dirty flag memorizing just true/false, keep the is of the input in focus and change it onChange and onBlur

Comment: this might be the solutions, thanks! I'll try this.

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava Still testing different answers